# DataTables in R: removes table border

Tags: r, dt

I am using the package DT to create a datatable. I want to remove the table border. Any suggestions?

```
datatable(head(mtcars), rownames = NULL, colnames = NULL, options = list(dom = "t"))
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot see any options to control this. Do you just need a simple HTML table with no borders / headers ?

Comment: I want to use it in Shiny and I want to include a datatable cell with an image and I want  a modal window to show on clicking the image. The modal window contains information on what the image is.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248958/datatable-remove-all-horizontal-borders/52262553

Answer (score 1):

I 'll provide an answer with `tableHTML` that you might find useful for such a task:

```
library(tableHTML)
#create the HTML table. setting border to zero will remove borders
tableHTML(mtcars, headers = rep(' ', 11), rownames = FALSE, border = 0,
          widths = rep('60', 11)) %>%
  #add some css odd rows to keep zebra colouring. You can choose any colour you like
  add_css_row(list('background-color', 'lightgray'), rows = even(1:nrow(mtcars)))
```

You can still change cell spacing, fonts, background colours or anything else you like with CSS using the `add_css_*` functions.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I use this in Shiny and can I make one of the columns an image. I want a modal window to show on clicking the image. The modal window contains information about the image.

Comment: `tableHTML` is compatible with [shiny](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/tableHTML.html). You could use an image within a cell I suppose (by providing the `<img ` tag as one of the cell's data) but I haven't really tried it. Anything you can do with HTML or CSS can be done with `tableHTML`. `javascript` is a bit trickier. Maybe worth posting a new question asking specifically that using a html table.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with shiny. But it does not render an image in a cell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288069/tablehtml-in-shiny-show-an-image-in-a-cell