# Positioning the text within Action Button in R shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I want to fit Resource Activity text within the given button such that Activity comes below the Resource in the button. Currently the complete word gets hidden because of less space of the button and I do not want to increase the space. Please help.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(

actionButton("buttonresinvthree", "Resource Activity",style="color: 
#000000; width:8%; ")
)
)
server <- function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Snapshot of button]

Comment: Please provide a working example that shows the problem.

Comment: Hi LyzandeR, Thank you so much for replying, please see my edited post, it has the snap of the button.

Comment: This is not a working example. This is a picture showing the problem. Add an example showing the code that creates the problem. You should provide us with a minimum example showing the problem you face. In your case that should include the ui code and a blank server function.

Comment: For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288069/tablehtml-in-shiny-show-an-image-in-a-cell/45289228#45289228) is a complete shiny question. The code should be minimal, i.e. use only code that is relevant to your problem.

Comment: Sure, I did exactly that, I guess now, you can help me.

Comment: In this one the button expands to cover the whole text (at least that is how it shows up on my browser). You could try `"Resource\nActivity"`.

Comment: I have set the width to 8% only, need to get the text in double lines, there is some css attribute which can do the job. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tableHTML)

ui <- dashboardPage(

 dashboardHeader(),
 dashboardSidebar(),
 dashboardBody(
  tags$head(tags$style(make_css(list('.btn', 'white-space', 'pre-wrap')))),
  actionButton("buttonresinvthree", HTML("Resource\nActivity"),
               style="color: #000000; width:8%; ")
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I added `tags$head...` to add `CSS` to the button (class btn) and used `\n` for the break line between `Resource\nActivity`.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set white-space to normal:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(

actionButton("buttonresinvthree", "Resource Activity",style="color: 
#000000; width:8%;white-space:normal;font-size:.8vw;")
)
)
server <- function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```