# DataTable: Remove all horizontal borders

Tags: r, dt

How do I remove all the horizontal borders to just the even/odd shading?

[image]

https://datatables.net/examples/styling/stripe.html

[image]

This doesn't work.

```
table.dataTable.row-border tbody th, 
table.dataTable.row-border tbody td, 
table.dataTable.display tbody th, 
table.dataTable.display tbody td {
  border: none;
}
```

I would also like to remove the top and bottom black borders. This doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
table.dataTable thead th {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-style: none;
}
table.dataTable tfoot th {
  border-top: 0;
  border-style: none;
}
table.dataTable .no-footer {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code to remove all the horizontal borders to just the even/odd shading:

```
datatable(mtcars[1:3,1:3], class = 'stripe')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the top border and the bottom border like this:

```
datatable(head(iris), 
          options=list(headerCallback = JS(
            "function( thead, data, start, end, display ) {
            $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').each(function(){
              $(this).css('color', 'red').css('border','none');
            });
            }"
            ),
            initComplete = JS(
            "function(settings) {
            var table = settings.oInstance.api(); 
            $(table.table().node()).removeClass('no-footer');
            }")))
```

Comment: Also just found that there is an option `style="bootstrap"` which removes all horizontal lines and the styles the table (rounded search bar etc) to fit with the rest of the bootstrap page elements.

Comment: For some reason this does not remove the bottom border for me, however I managed to override the preset bottom border by using !important: '.dataTables-wrapper.no-footer .dataTables-scrollBody{ border-bottom: none !important;}'